# What is wrong with my approach of using MLP to make a chess engine?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, mlp

I’m making a chess engine using machine learning, and I’m experiencing problems debugging it. I need help figuring out what is wrong with my program, and I would appreciate any help.

I made my research and borrowed ideas from multiple successful projects. The idea is to use reinforcement learning to teach NN to differentiate between strong and weak positions.

I collected 3 million games with Elo over 2000 and used my own method to label them. After researching hundreds of games, I found out, that it’s safe to assume that in the last 10 turns of any game, the balance doesn’t change, and the winning side has a strong advantage. So I picked positions from the last 10 turns and made two labels: one for a win for white and zero for black. I didn’t include any draw positions. To avoid bias, I have picked even numbers of positions labeled with wins for both sides and even number of positions for both sides with the next turn.

Each position I represented by a vector with the length of 773 elements. Every piece on every square of a chess board, together with castling rights and a next turn, I coded with ones and zeros.  My sequential model has an input layer with 773 neurons and an output layer with one single neuron. I have used a three hidden layer deep MLP with 1546, 500 and 50 hidden units for layers 1, 2, and 3 respectively with dropout regularization value of 20% on each. Hidden layers are connected with the non- linear activation function ReLU, while the final output layer has a sigmoid output. I used binary crossentropy loss function and the Adam algorithm with all default parameters, except for the learning rate, which I set to 0.0001.

I used 3 percent of the positions for validation. During the first 10 epochs, validation accuracy gradually went up from 90 to 92%, just one percent behind training accuracy. Further training led to overfitting, with training accuracy going up, and validation accuracy going down.

I tested the trained model on multiple positions by hand, and got pretty bad results. Overall the model can predict which side is winning, if that side has more pieces or pawns close to a conversion square. Also it gives the side with a next turn a small advantage (0.1). But overall it doesn’t make much sense. In most cases it heavily favors black (by ~0.3) and doesn’t properly take into account the setup. For instance, it labels the starting position as ~0.0001, as if the black side has almost 100% chance to win. Sometimes irrelevant transformation of a position results in unpredictable change of the evaluation. One king and one queen from each side usually is viewed as lost position for white (0.32), unless black king is on certain square, even though it doesn’t really change the balance on the chessboard.

What I did to debug the program:

1. To make sure I have not made any mistakes, I analyzed, how each position is being recorded, step by step. Then I picked a dozen of positions from the final numpy array, right before training, and converted it back to analyze them on a regular chess board.
2. I used various numbers of positions from the same game (1 and 6) to make sure, that using too many similar positions is not the cause for the fast overfitting. By the way, even one position for each game in my database resulted in 3 million data set, which should be sufficient according to some research papers.
3. To make sure that the positions I use are not too simple, I analyzed them. 1.3 million of them had 36 points in pieces (knights, bishops, rooks, and queens; pawns were not included in the count), 1.4 million - 19 points, and only 0.3 million - had less.

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions; your question is way too broad, please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Also, question as is has nothing to do with `python`, `tensorflow`, or `reinforcement-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced with `neural-network` & `mlp`).

Answer (score 0):

Some things you could try:

1. Add unit tests and asserts wherever possible. E.g. if you know that some value is never supposed to get negative, add an assert to check that this condition really holds.
2. Print shapes of all tensors to check that you have really created the architecture you intended.
3. Check if your model outperforms some simple baseline model.
4. You say your model overfits, so maybe simplify it / add regularization?
5. Check how your model performs on the simplest positions. E.g. can it recognize a checkmate?